# A party with strange people: Who are they?

Tags: word, wordplay

In a party, there were many puzzlers. Some of these were:

> 1. A japanese hacker
> 2. An infinite loop
> 3. A novice programmer
> 4. Two magic words
> 5. An exclusive gate
> 6. A pokémon
> 7. A second derivative
> 8. A navigator
> 9. A man in search of a pseudonym
> 10. A king named Rames
> 11. An artificial ghoul from japan
> 12. The only true fanatic
> 13. A gamer expressing sudden pain
> 14. A pixelated Joe
> 15. A black bear
> 16. A stylish logician
> 17. The FSM
> 18. The most prolific writer
> 19. A Cyclic postdoc mathematician of order 4
> 20. A person from the land of Rampart
> 21. Mr K, happy to update his software
> 22. One that is too slim to be seen from afar
> 23. A sunflower
> 24. A winged tiger who rules
> 25. A cat with an evil smile
> 26. An unusual atmospheric phenomenon
> 27. A Java developer who considers things
> 28. A man from the Kiasyd bloodline
> 29. An aircraft concerned about privacy
> 30. An iOS dev with "pretty cool" apps

Beyond these famous ones mentioned, there are many, many more.

In fact, you may be in the party too. Can you figure out who was each person in this list?

Comment: Aww, you made my clue too easy. But I'm cool with that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The names you list, are people that appear on the top users page for this month.

A japanese hacker

> Hackiisan

An infinite loop

> GOTO 0

A novice programmer

> CodeNewbie

Two magic words

> squeamish ossifrage

An exclusive gate

> xnor

A pokémon

> [Bailey M](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11475/bailey-m%20%22bailey-m)

A second derivative

> f'' (thanks to dmg)

A navigator

> Nautilus

A man in search of a pseudonym

> NeedAName

A king named Rames

> Kingrames

An artificial ghoul

> [Anachor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15544/anachor)

The only true fanatic

> [IanMacdonald](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10399/ian-macdonald) (he's 'on top' - but just for the month.. not all time)

A gamer expressing sudden pain

> gamow

A pixelated Joe

> [Joe Z](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/88/joe-z) (pixels in avatar icon)

A black bear

> [Thomas Pornin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4797/thomas-pornin)

A stylish logician

> LogicianWithAHat

The FSM

> [Ben Frankel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11100/ben-frankel) (has the 'Flying Spaghetti Monster' as display picture)

The most prolific writer

> [James Webster](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4729/james-webster) (very elaborate profile...)

A Cyclic postdoc mathematician of order 4

> [Julian Rosen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2627/julian-rosen)

A person from the land of Rampart

> [Roland](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13237/roland)

Mr K, happy to update his software

> [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)

One that is too slim to be seen from afar

> Sleafar

A sunflower

> [alexmc](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12206/alexmc)

The powerful master of us all

> Emrakul (as moderator?)

A cat with an evil smile

> [psmears](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10781/psmears)

An unusual atmospheric phenomenon

> GentlePurpleRain

Java developer who considers things

> [dennisdeems](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4385/dennisdeems)

A man from the Kiasyd bloodline

> Marconius

An aircraft concerned about privacy

> [Jet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15786/jet)

An iOS dev with "pretty cool" apps

> [Luke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10851/luke) (thanks to dmg)

Comment: second derivative is f"

Comment: Why is Marconius a navigator?

Comment: And the last one is "Luke" according to his profile.

Comment: As for marconius - I was referencing Marconi, but he wasn't really a navigator I guess. I'll correct if I find a better match.

Comment: Corrected 'Ditto' for the pokemon, seemed a better fit.

Comment: I edited #26, since it was too general (there are thousands of rubik cube enthusiasts)

Comment: Tweaked the answer for 26. Struggling to coplete the last few now.

Comment: Added more detail to #11. The last two were also the hardest for me, and involves thinking different from the other solutions

Comment: Well, I'll take that as a not-so-subtle hint 'ghosts_in_the_code' wasn't the intended answer.. :)

Comment: Also, the answer of #6 was correct at first. Ditto is not nearly as popular as any other user in this list - remember I'm talking about the famous ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29261/discussion-between-ivan-barreto-and-tim-couwelier).

Comment: @TimCouwelier: A link to each one's profile would be easier to understand some of the clues.

Comment: @CodeNewbie : Yea, I'll try and sort that out. Wanted answers first, then lay-out after. (Assuming I can figure out how to do the links easily)